# jquery datetime picker addon default time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So the default default time (not talking about the date) is 12:00 AM, how do i set it to something else?

talking about this addon http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is straight from the documentation on the link you posted.

```
$('#example7').datetimepicker({
    hour: 13,
    minute: 15
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i am having the same problem. The time is never set, always at 01:00

Comment: @Glen, there are two datetimepicker Addons. Be sure you have the correct.